# Lanzar script en base al idioma de la página

Tags: javascript, wordpress, url

Estoy realizando unos cambios en una web que estoy administrando y se me ha presentado el siguiente problema:
La página está en dos idiomas (Inglés y Español) y dispone de un ChatBot de soporte.
El tema es que ahora queremos tener este chat en el idioma seleccionado de la página, tenemos dos scripts diferentes, uno para cada idioma, pero no tengo claro como hacerlo funcionar en Wordpress.

Lo que tengo hecho es lo siguiente, pero no termina de funcionar:

```
   if (window.location.pathname === '/es/*') {
     <script  lang="es" client-url="https..." defer></script>;
   }
else {
   <script  lang="en" client-url="https..." defer></script>;
   }
```

Comment: Por qué dices que no funciona?

Comment: Eso no es Javascript válido, aparte de que no puedes anidar etiquetas `<script>`

Comment: @PabloLozano, gracias por tu inestimable ayuda

Comment: Lamento el error, en realidad el código está en un fichero js, así que el script que abre y cierra no está en el documento.

Comment: Sería mucho mejor que esté la etiqueta script en el documento, y desde el script cambiarle el atributo SRC. Sería lo más facil